# Access violation variavel tipo TXSDate

Tags: delphi

Estou realizando a integração com o webservice da Total Express Transportes e fazendo a importação do wsdl disponibilizado por eles
foi criado varias propriedades onde os tipos são TXSDecimal e TXSDate.

Ao tentar atribuir um valor para uma propriedade que tem o tipo como TXSDate esta ocorrendo o erro de access violation.

Abaixo segue o código que estou desenvolvendo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Registra : RegistraColetaRequest;
  AuxEncomendas : Encomendas;
  AuxNfe : DocFiscalNFe;   
  encom : Encomenda;
  nota : NFe;    
begin    
  Registra := RegistraColetaRequest.Create;
  TXSDate.Create;

  encom := Encomenda.Create;
  encom.IdCliente := 'teste';
  encom.DestNome := 'Destinatario teste';

  SetLength(AuxEncomendas, 1);
  Registra.CodRemessa := '1315';  

  nota := NFe.Create;
  nota.NfeChave := '12315645645645564';

  //Nesta linha ocorre o erro comentado
  nota.NfeData.AsDate := Date;

  SetLength(AuxNfe, 1);
  AuxNfe[0] := nota;

  encom.DocFiscalNFe := AuxNfe;

  AuxEncomendas[0] := encom;
  Registra.Encomendas := AuxEncomendas;

 (HTTPRIO as webservice_v24_totalPortType).RegistraColeta(Registra);    
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for um `TXSDateTime` você não pode atribuir diretamente. Algo como...

```
uses
  Soap.XSBuiltIns;
...

var
  vDataTxs: TXSDateTime;
begin
  vDataTxs := TXSDateTime.Create;
  vDataTxs.XSToNative(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Data_Desejada) + 'T00:00:00.000-03:00');
...
end;
```

Agora para recuperar esta data de volta (você recebeu através do xml) se atente a utilizar o `.AsUTCDateTime`.